# Facing Python import issues inside my deployed container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, numpy, dockerfile

I have a Python application that can be executed on my local machine. I want to deploy the app by containerizing it and pushing it to the Docker repo.

I can containerize the app by using either Conda or a virtualenv.

```
# Conda Dockerfile
FROM continuumio/anaconda3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app

ARG APP_NAME=app

COPY /config/environment/environment.yml .
RUN conda env create --name $APP_NAME --file environment.yml

SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "app", "/bin/bash", "-c"]

EXPOSE 8100-8200
COPY /scripts/python/main.py .
ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "--no-capture-output", "-n", "app", "python", "main.py"]
```

```
# virtualenv Dockerfile
FROM python:3.7-slim

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app

ARG APP_NAME=app

COPY /config/environment/requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r config/environment/requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8100-8200
COPY /scripts/python/main.py .

# Define the command to run the application
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

Using the following dependency files.

```
name: app
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - colorama=0.4.4
  - numba=0.45.1
  - pandas=1.1.0
  - pdtable=0.0.8
  - pint=0.16.1
  - pip=20.2.4
  - pytest=6.2.5
  - pytest-cov=3.0.0
  - python=3.7.9
  - startables=0.8.4
  - tabulate=0.8.10 
  - xlrd=1.2.0
  - xlsxwriter=1.3.7
  - pip:
    - cachelib==0.10.2
    - cycler==0.11.0
    - dash==2.12.1
    - dash-core-components==2.0.0
    - dash-extensions==0.1.11
    - dash-html-components==2.0.0
    - dash-renderer==1.9.1
    - dash-table==5.0.0
    - editorconfig==0.12.3
    - flake8==4.0.1
    - flask-caching==2.0.1
    - fonttools==4.38.0
    - jsbeautifier==1.14.9
    - kiwisolver==1.4.5
    - lxml==4.9.3
    - matplotlib==3.5.3
    - more-itertools==8.14.0
    - pillow==9.5.0
    - pyparsing==3.1.1
    - python-docx==0.8.11
    - pyyaml==6.0.1
    - scipy==1.6.0
    - tables==3.5.1
  # TEST
  - black
  - flake8
  - flake8-comprehensions
  - flake8-black
  - isort
```

```
cachelib
colorama
cycler
dash
dash-core-components
dash-extensions
dash-html-components
dash-renderer
dash-table
editorconfig
flake8
flask-caching
fonttools
jsbeautifier
kiwisolver
lxml
matplotlib
more-itertools
numba
pandas
pdtable
pillow
pint
pyparsing
pytest
pytest-cov
python-docx
pyyaml
scipy
startables
tabulate
tables
xlrd
xlsxwriter
```

I have no issues with the container created using the YAML file, even though the container is three times bigger than the virtualenv container. However, the virtualenv Docker app has import issues

```
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 1 of 8: Operation not permitted
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 1048576 current, 1048576 max
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 2 of 8: Operation not permitted
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 1048576 current, 1048576 max
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 3 of 8: Operation not permitted
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 1048576 current, 1048576 max
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 4 of 8: Operation not permitted
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 1048576 current, 1048576 max
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 5 of 8: Operation not permitted
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 1048576 current, 1048576 max
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 6 of 8: Operation not permitted
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 1048576 current, 1048576 max
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 7 of 8: Operation not permitted
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 1048576 current, 1048576 max
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from frontend import run_dash
  File "/usr/src/app/frontend/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .app import run_dash
  File "/usr/src/app/frontend/app.py", line 18, in <module>
    from frontend.app_component_factory import (
  File "/usr/src/app/frontend/app_component_factory.py", line 7, in <module>
    from app.common import constants as c
  File "/usr/src/app/app/common/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .errors import user_error, user_warning, infeasible_solution_error
  File "/usr/src/app/app/common/errors.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app.common.constants import local_session_id
  File "/usr/src/app/app/common/constants.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pandas import DataFrame
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 150, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
```

This looks like a numpy versioning issue, but I am not too certain.

```
# conda numpy
Name: numpy
Version: 1.21.5
Summary: NumPy is the fundamental package for array computing with Python.
Home-page: https://www.numpy.org
Author: Travis E. Oliphant et al.
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: c:\users\jigsi\anaconda3\envs\of_dev_dash2\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: tables, startables, scipy, pdtable, pandas, numexpr, numba, mkl-random, mkl-fft, matplotlib
```

```
# virtualenv numpy
Name: numpy
Version: 1.21.6
Summary: NumPy is the fundamental package for array computing with Python.
Home-page: https://www.numpy.org
Author: Travis E. Oliphant et al.
Author-email:
License: BSD
Location: c:\users\jigsi\appdata\dev\harmonica\harmonica_py37\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: matplotlib, numba, numexpr, pandas, pdtable, scipy, startables, tables
```

Comment: The traceback error is truncated.

Answer (score 1):

Given the issues with OpenBLAS and the information about the dependencies, it's important to make sure that OpenBLAS and its dependencies are properly installed and configured on your system.

```
pip install --upgrade matplotlib numba numexpr pandas pdtable scipy startables tables
```

You can also look at the possible reasons below:

Check the system limits:

```
 ulimit -a
```

Adjust environment varibles:

```
export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=4  # Adjust the number based on your system
```

Check system-wide thread limits:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
```

I hope your problem is solved